# Is there a hypernym for acidity and basicity?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms, science

I was wondering if there was a single word for what the pH scale measures, with no particular bias to either the acidic end (acidity) or basic end (basicity) of the spectrum. From Wikipedia:

> In chemistry, pH (/piːˈeɪtʃ/) is a numeric scale used to specify the acidity or basicity (alkalinity) of an aqueous solution

I could not find a single word term that encompassed both acidity and basicity (or alkalinity) in the article or elsewhere , which could be used as follows:

> In chemistry, pH (/piːˈeɪtʃ/) is a numeric scale used to specify the _______ of an aqueous solution

Comment: Is there a chemistry.SE? They might have a technical term for it.

Comment: '... hydrogen ion concentration...'.

Comment: What's wrong with, "... used to specify the ***pH*** of an aqueous solution"? (Well, obviously not in the definition of pH- which is why they reverted to "acidity or basicity")

Comment: Well, obviously any term you use is going to have a bias, since either acid or alkaline will be at the low end of the spectrum.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that's the right answer! Could you please make it an answer so I can vote for it? There is a Chemistry.SE, so this question would probably make sense there too.

Comment: Sorry, Gaurav. I don't think that 'hydrogen ion concentration' really fits in on a general English website. By all means ask/answer on Chemistry SE, where the register is fine. Though as a chemist, I'd just use 'pH' most of the time (it obviously wouldn't work here, as Jim says). '... how acidic or alkaline ...' is probably impossible to improve on.

Comment: Well maybe "proticity" might work but it's rather property of solvent

Answer (score 4):

A more generic term would indeed be an improvement over *acidity*, which for chemists is nonetheless like *altitude* and carries no bias when used.  Same for *basicity*, which just doesn't happen to be a popular term.  *Alkalinity* also refers to the entire pH range but indeed favors higher-pH occasions.  Also too bad is that high acidity means low pH.

Comment: The abbreviation 'pH' is often used as the requested hypernym.

Answer (score 3):

> In chemistry, pH (/piːˈeɪtʃ/) is a numeric scale used to specify the
>   *lability* of an aqueous solution

"Lability" is often used in reference to proton exchange with acids, bases. A proton that is "highly labile" is said to dissociate from a compound easily, while "low lability" would refer to a Bronsted-Lowry base (i.e. the base wants to keep it's protons and therefore does not lose them easily).

Wikipedia doesn't have much on it but feel free to read anyway: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lability

So I might say, "This compound would make a great acid because it has a proton that is very labile." Of course, the actual effects of acidity and basicity depend on what else is in solution but I think you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but consider ***acid-base ratio***.

> *In chemistry, pH is a numeric scale used to specify the [acid-base ratio](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22the+acid+base%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=ezqIVrP3JMLXUcTqiMgH#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22the+acid+base+ratio%22) of an aqueous solution.*